# Can anyone explain the output of apache-beam streaming pipeline with Fixed Window of 60 seconds?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have written a pipeline , which reads streaming data from PubSub, and aggregate the results and write the result to Bigquery.
The pipeline is working fine and writing agg result to Bigquery table.
But, I am not able to understand, how its calculating the result.

Below is my code of apache-beam:

```
import json
import os
import typing
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import GoogleCloudOptions
from apache_beam.io.gcp.internal.clients import bigquery
from apache_beam.transforms.sql import SqlTransform

table_spec1 = bigquery.TableReference(
    projectId=<PROJECT_ID>,
    datasetId='training',
    tableId='dflow_agg')


SCHEMA = {
        "fields": [
            {
                "name": 'Name',
                "type": "STRING",
                
            },
            {
                "name": 'avg_sal',
                "type": "FLOAT64"
            },
            {
                "name": 'window_start',
                "type": "STRING",
                "mode": "NULLABLE"
            },
              {
                "name": 'window_end',
                "type": "STRING",
                "mode": "NULLABLE"
            }
        ]
    }

pipeline_options = PipelineOptions( streaming=True)

class ProcessWords(beam.DoFn):
  def process(self, ele):
    yield eval(ele)





def run():
    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:


        out= (
            p
            | "Read from Pub/Sub subscription" >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription="projects/<PROJECT_ID>/subscriptions/Test-sub")
            | "Decode and parse Json" >> beam.Map(lambda element: element.decode("utf-8"))
            |"Formatting " >> beam.ParDo(ProcessWords()) #.with_output_types(CommonLog)
            | "Create beam Row" >> beam.Map(lambda x: beam.Row(Name=str(x[0]),Stream=str(x[1]),Salary=int(x[2])))
            
            |"window" >> beam.WindowInto(beam.window.FixedWindows(30))  
            | SqlTransform(
                """
                    SELECT
                    Name,
                    AVG(Salary) AS avg_sal
                    FROM PCOLLECTION
                    GROUP BY Name
                    
                """)
   
        | "Assemble Dictionary" >> beam.Map(
        lambda row,
        window=beam.DoFn.WindowParam: {
            "Name": row.Name,
            "avg_sal": row.avg_sal,
            "window_start": window.start.to_rfc3339(),
            "window_end": window.end.to_rfc3339()
        })



            | "Write to BigQuery" >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
                table=table_spec1,
                dataset='training',
                schema=SCHEMA,
                create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
                write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
            )
            # |beam.MapTuple(lambda N,S,M : {"Name":N,"Stream":S,"Marks":M})
            # | beam.Map(print)
        )
    

    # p.run()
if __name__ == '__main__':
  run()
```

I have a python code, which publishes msg to a PubSub topic with a sleep time of 5 seconds.
Below is my publisher code.

```
import time
import random
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1

project_id = "<PROJECT_ID>"
topic_name = "Test"
publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()

topic_path = publisher.topic_path(project_id, topic_name)
i=0
while i < 101:
    name=['A','B','C']
    sal=[10,12,11,23,77,54,23,21,4,9,5,22,19]
    stream=["Stream1","Stream2","Stream3"]

    data = '{}'.format((random.choice(name),random.choice(stream),random.choice(sal)))
    # Data must be a bytestring
    data = data.encode("utf-8")
    future = publisher.publish(topic_path, data)
    print(data)
    future.result()
    time.sleep(5)
    i+=1
```

I have printed the msgs which are published to the topic and below are 20 msg from beginning.

```
b"('B', 'Stream2', 23)"
b"('A', 'Stream3', 77)"
b"('C', 'Stream2', 10)"
b"('B', 'Stream2', 10)"
b"('B', 'Stream3', 10)"
b"('B', 'Stream2', 19)"
b"('C', 'Stream1', 11)"
b"('C', 'Stream2', 22)"
b"('A', 'Stream2', 12)"
b"('B', 'Stream1', 11)"
b"('A', 'Stream2', 23)"
b"('C', 'Stream3', 23)"
b"('A', 'Stream2', 4)"
b"('C', 'Stream2', 22)"
b"('B', 'Stream2', 4)"
b"('C', 'Stream2', 10)"
b"('B', 'Stream3', 11)"
b"('C', 'Stream2', 10)"
b"('C', 'Stream2', 22)"
b"('A', 'Stream2', 19)"
```

Bigquery results when ordering by Window start time looks like this:

select * from training.dflow_agg
order by window_start

[Bigquery Table data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfoSo.png)

Now, I want to understand, how the avg is calculated.

Case1:
If window size is 60 sec, then the first window will contain element

```
b"('B', 'Stream2', 23)"
b"('A', 'Stream3', 77)"
b"('C', 'Stream2', 10)"
b"('B', 'Stream2', 10)"
b"('B', 'Stream3', 10)"
b"('B', 'Stream2', 19)"
```

**So, The Avg of A will be 77-> This is correct,as there is only one A and Avg of one element is same.**

**Avg of B should be 23+10+10+10+19= 72/4 =18 ( Divide by 4, because total 4 B's are there)**

**Why C is not in the Same window start and window end time,as of A and B, because C was also published within 30 sec of window time (See, pubsub output above)**

Can anyone explain me the output.

Thanks in advance.

Above all things I have tried